# How can I clear the cin`s buffer?

Tags: c++, cout, cin

```
{
    int val;
    string str;
    cin >> val;    
    cin >> str;
}
```

When I write C++ program, I met a problem.
I define a int variable "val", and I write this：    cin >> val, but I input is 'g'.
When I write next statement     cin >> str; the     cin directly use the 'g' again,
but this is not my want.

I want clear the     cin buffer so that I can input the correct number to     str.

I have find a solution to this problem. Here is the solution

```
{
    int val;
    string str;
    cin >> val;    
    cin >> str;
}
```

Now I want know that if exist a more better way and How to clear current buffer on Linux

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your codes are identical.

Comment: Not a good duplicate: that's C, this is C++.

Answer (score 1):

```
cin>>val;    
cin.clear();
cin.sync();
// ...
```